# how to import a schema to a XML file

Tags: xml, xsd

How do you import an XML schema from a *.xsd file to an XML file? What instructions should you use?
When I write something like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <xs:include schemaLocation="wix.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"></Wix>
```

then I get "*the document can't contain multiple root elements*"

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Reference an XSD in an XML file?

Comment: yes, I want to reference an XSD in an XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi wix.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`import`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_import.asp) or [`include`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_include.asp).

Comment: When I write something like: <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="wix.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"></Wix> then I get "the document can't contain multiple root elements.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 - you need to set the XML namespace `xs` to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.  Your `targetNamespace` should be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi%22%3E` (or perhaps rather than a targetNamespace set that to a namespace such as `wi` and use `wi` for your elements in that namespace).